# A derivation operation which produces a definite integral

Tags: calculus

We are all familiar with the derivative, and the anti-derivative:

$$
f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x) dx
$$

---

I am interested in a similar relationship but for definite integrals (with all the limitations that this entails). The definite integral is:

$$
F(b)-F(a) = \int_a^b f(x)dx
$$

One can take the approach that infinitely many functions, once integrate under $[a,b]$, will produce the same area and that therefore the operation is not uniquely defined.

But, in the answer to another question, "localization" is mentioned as producing a unique answer:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/498064/given-the-action-derive-the-lagrangian-fields-and-non-fields

Are there any resources (online) about "localization".
Can anyone expand upon this answer?

---

Let me attempt. One localizes an infinitesimal segment on the curve $[a,a+d h]$. The definite integral becomes:

$$
F(a+dh)-F(a) = \int_{a}^{a+dh} f(x)dx
$$

This is very close to the definition of a derivative by the limit:

$$
f(x)=\lim_{dh\to0}\frac{F(a+dh)-F(a)}{dh}
$$

except that it's missing the $dh$ part. Instead, perhaps we can define $F(a+dh)-F(a)$ as the differential form $dF$? In this case:

$$
dF=\int_a^{a+dh}f(x)dx
$$

Any validity to this? Any know relationship between total derivatives and definite integrals?

Comment: It sounds like you're just looking for the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Well, I asked for a method to derive the Lagrangian knowing only the action (in the physics StackExchange) and I was told it was impossible because the definite integral erases the function. I am looking for the conditions where this would be possible.

Comment: If you just know the integral for some fixed $a$ and $b$, then it's obviously impossible to reconstruct the integrand. If you know $\int_a^x f(x) \, dx$ for all $x$, then you can.